# converter string para double elasticsearch

Tags: string, conversão-de-tipo, double, elasticsearch

olá, pessoal to precisando de uma ajuda com elasticsearch.
estou tentando fazer uma conversão por script,  de um campo string, para double, mas infelizmente, não estou conseguindo. o ultimo script que fiz foi esse:

```
def cod=0;  if(String.valueOf(doc['codProduto.keyword'].value)!=null){ String sCod = doc['codProduto.keyword'].value; cod = Double.parseDouble(sCod);} return cod;
```

porem retorna esse erro

**"caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason" : "A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"**

mas se eu fizer o script dessa forma:

```
def cod=0;  if(doc['codProduto'].size()>=0){ String sCod = doc['codProduto.keyword'].value; cod = Double.parseDouble(sCod);} return cod;
```

retorna esse erro:
**
"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [codProduto] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
**

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, então estou postando a resposta, caso alguem precise

```
"int cod = 0; if(doc['codProduto.keyword'].empty){return 0;}else{cod = Integer.parseInt(doc['codProduto.keyword'].value);} return cod;"
```